# Load more on auto scroll doesn't work on mobile

Tags: javascript, jquery, scroll

I have the following code, which works in desktop browsers, however in mobile it doesnt work when scrolling, only when stopping.
How can this is fixed?

```
$(document).ready(function(){
   $(window).scroll(function() {
      var loadMore = $("#load-more-videos");

      if($(window).scrollTop() + $(window).height() ==            
         $(document).height())
            loadMore.click();
  });
});
```

Answer (score 0):

Try this

```
$(document).on('touchstart touchend touchmove', function(){
     $(window).trigger('scroll');
});
```

Comment: Nope.. Still it waits for the touch to finish